# form to PHP mail with dynamic Javascript table

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

I'm trying to setup a form that will be sent by email, I have a dynamic javascript table, that rows of data can be added and deleted by the user, and I have a PHP to mail it, i managed to post all the first table data to the PHP and send it, but I'm lost on how to post the dynamic table also (as a table) into the mail.
if anyone have ideas on how to take this entire form with the way it's formatted and send it to an email - thanks ahead.

here is the javascript of the form creation:

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;    
    var validate_Noof_columns = (colCount - 1); // •No Of Columns to be Validated on Text.
    for(var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) { 
        var text = window.document.getElementById('input'+j).value;

        if (j == validate_Noof_columns) {
            row = table.insertRow(2); // •location of new row.
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {       
            var text = window.document.getElementById('input'+i).value;
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                if(i == (colCount - 1)) {  // Replace last column with delete button
    newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type='button' value='Del' onclick='removeRow(this)'/>"; break;
                } else  {
                    newcell.innerHTML = text;
                    window.document.getElementById('input'+i).value = '';
                }
            }   
        }else if (text != 'undefined' && text.trim() == ''){ 
            alert('input'+j+' is EMPTY');break;
        }  
    }   
}
function removeRow(onclickTAG) {
    // Iterate till we find TR tag. 
    while ( (onclickTAG = onclickTAG.parentElement)  && onclickTAG.tagName != 'TR' );
            onclickTAG.parentElement.removeChild(onclickTAG);      
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <form action="results.php" method="post" name="order_form" acceptcharset="utf-8">
        <div align="center"><span class="auto-style1"><strong>Order form</strong></span><strong><br class="auto-style1">
   </strong></div>
        <div id="left" align="center">
            <label for="request" id="request">Request</label><input type="checkbox" name="request" id="request">
            <label for="binding_order">Binding Order</label><input type="checkbox" name="binding_order">
            <div></div>
            <table style="width: 600px;" align="center">
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 156px; height: 26px;" id="cellleft"><label for="order">Order</label></td>
     <td id="cellleft" style="height: 26px"><input type="checkbox" name="order"></td>
     <td style="width:100px; height: 26px;"></td>
     <td style="width: 140px; height: 26px;" id="cellright"> Name</td>
     <td id="cellright" style="height: 26px">
               <select name="shop_name">
                   <option>...</option>
                   <option>shop1</option>
                   <option>shop2</option>
                   <option>shop3</option>
          
               </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 156px" id="cellleft">
      <label for="spare_parts">Spare Parts</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellleft">
      <input type="checkbox" name="spare_parts">
     </td>
     <td style="width:100px">
     </td>
     <td style="width: 140px" id="cellright">
      <label for="employee">Employee</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellright">
      <input type="text" dir="ltr" name="employee" style="width: 224px">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 156px" id="cellleft">
      <label for="customized">Customized</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellleft">
      <input id="customized" type="checkbox">
     </td>
     <td style="width:100px">
     </td>
     <td style="width: 140px" id="cellright">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellright">
      <input type="text" name="date" style="width: 224px" id="datepicker">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 156px" id="cellleft">
      <label for="archive_order">Archive Order</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellleft">
      <input name="archive_order" type="checkbox">
     </td>
     <td colspan="3">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="cellleft" style="width: 156px">
      <label for="call">Call</label>
     </td>
     <td id="cellleft">
      <input name="call" type="checkbox">
     </td>
     <td align="right" colspan="3">
     <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send">
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>         
        </div>
     <br>

    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" align="center">
         <table id="partsTable" border="1px" bordercolor="gray" width="600px">
       <th class="auto-style2">Part</th>
       <th class="auto-style2">Color</th>
    <th class="auto-style2">Style</th>
    <th class="auto-style2">Defect</th>
    <th class="auto-style2">Purchase Date</th>
    <th class="auto-style2" colspan="2">Client</th>
    <th></th>
    <tr>
         <td><select name="part" id="input0">
              <option>...</option>
              <option>FRAME</option>
              <option>FRONT</option>
              <option>TEMPLE</option>
              <option>LENSES</option>
          </select>
         </td>
   <td><select name="color" id="input1">
              <option>...</option>
              <option>GOLD</option>
              <option>BLACK</option>
              <option>SILVER</option>
          </select>
   </td>
   <td><select name="style" id="input2">
              <option>...</option>
              <option>STD</option>
              <option>UNI</option>
              <option>LITE</option>
              <option>IMP</option>
              <option>ERGO</option>
              <option>YPS</option>
              <option>LITE ACETATE</option>
              <option>YPS+</option>
          </select>
   </td>
   <td><input name="defect" type="text" id="input3"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="pdate" id="input4"></td>
         <td><input name="client" type="text" id="input5"></td>
         <td><input type="button" id="input6" onClick="addRow('partsTable')" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
     </form>  
    </div>
```

Comment: You can use a template engine to combine your page server side with your posted values

Comment: Hi Paul, my question is how?
I haven't used template engine before, and currently I only managed to get just the first (top table) values to my PHP mail send.